# Don't understand the inner function in python

Tags: python, function, parameters

I have this problem:

> `cons(a, b)` constructs a pair, and `car(pair)` and `cdr(pair)` returns the first and last element of that pair. For example, `car(cons(3, 4))` returns `3`, and `cdr(cons(3, 4))` returns `4`.
>
> Given this implementation of cons:
>
> ```
> def cons(a, b):
>     def pair(f):
>         return f(a, b)
>     return pair
> ```
>
> Implement `car` and `cdr`.

I don't get the function.

It has an inner function and calls an other function in the return. As far as I understood the inner functions is that these functions should depend on the functions above them.  In this case on `cons(..)`.

But the function is not using `a` or `b`. And why is the function `f` there? The task is to implement `car` and `cdr`, and function `f` should be given.

So could someone explain me this function? And how could I start with the task?

Comment: IMO, `cons` should return a tuple, not a function

Comment: @cricket_007: but `cons()` is part of their assignment. So `cdr()` and `car()` will have to pass in a function that takes either the first or last argument passed.

Comment: @Martijn Right, just having a hard time thinking about how you would call this other than `cons(a, b)(func)`

Comment: @cricket_007 That's *exactly* how you would call it; it's an implementation of lambda calculus, and functions are the *only* kind of value you have. There *is* no tuple data structure, only functions that are defined to obey laws like `car(cons(a, b)) == a` and `cons(car(f), cdr(f)) == f`.

Answer (score 31):

First of all: Python function objects are *first class objects*. A `def` statement results in a new function object, and you can retrieve that object by using the function name:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 'foo was called'
...
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x11b3d8ae8>
```

What this means is that you can assign that object to other names too, and you can pass them as parameters to function calls. You can then later on call the function object by adding `(...)` to the reference:

```
>>> bar = foo
>>> bar()
'foo was called'
```

The function name is assigned to in the current namespace. In a module, that's the globals, but in a function such as `cons`, the name is added as a local. `return pair` in the `cons` function then returns the function object `pair` to the caller.

And function parameters such as `f` and `a` and `b` are also variables; if you pass in a function object as a parameter, then `parameter_name(...)` will call `paramater_name` and pass in any arguments in the `...` part. `f(a, b)` calls `f` and passes in `a` and `b`.

The next item to understand are [*closures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)); closures are an extra namespace attached to function objects, for variables from a surrounding scope.

In the following example, `spam` is a name in the closure of the `bar` function:

```
>>> def foo():
...     spam = 'Vikings'
...     def bar():
...         return spam
...     return bar
...
>>> foo()
<function foo.<locals>.bar at 0x11b44bf28>
>>> foo()()
'Vikings'
```

Calling `foo()` returns a new function object; the `bar()` function inside of `foo()`. Calling that returned function object produces `'Vikings'`, the value of the `spam` variable in the `foo` function. How did `bar()` get access to that? Via the closure:

```
>>> foo().__closure__
(<cell at 0x11b3c05b8: str object at 0x11b469180>,)
>>> foo().__closure__[0].cell_contents
'Vikings'
```

So nested functions can have access to names from the surrounding scope via closures. (Side note: it's not the *value* that's stored in a closure, it's the *variable*. The variable can change over time, and just like other variables accessing the name later will reflect the new value; if `spam` was changed later on, calling `bar()` again would return the new value).

Now to your function: `cons()` creates an inner function `pair()`, and `pair()` has access to the parameters `a` and `b` via its closure:

```
>>> def cons(a, b):
...     def pair(f):
...         return f(a, b)
...     return pair
...
>>> cons(42, 81)
<function cons.<locals>.pair at 0x11b46f048>
>>> pair_42_81 = cons(42, 81)
>>> pair_42_81.__closure__
(<cell at 0x11b3c02b8: int object at 0x10f59a750>, <cell at 0x11b3c05b8: int object at 0x10f59ac30>)
>>> pair_42_81.__closure__[0].cell_contents
42
>>> pair_42_81.__closure__[1].cell_contents
81
```

The `pair()` function takes a parameter `f`, and *calls* that parameter, passing in `a` and `b`. Lets see what happens when we pass in `print`.

`print` is a function too, it is an object that you can call, and it writes the arguments to the console with spaces in between:

```
>>> print
<built-in function print>
>>> print('arg1', 'arg2')
arg1 arg2
```

If you passed that to the `pair()` function that `cons()` returns, you can see what `f(a, b)` does:

```
>>> pair_42_81(print)
42 81
```

`print`, passed to `pair()`, is assigned to `f`, and `f(a, b)` is exactly the same thing as `print(a, b)`.

We can see that `print()` was called because the values are written out to the console. But you could also create a function that returns a new value. Say you have a function that adds up two numbers, and returns that value:

```
>>> def add(first, second):
...     return first + second
...
>>> add(42, 81)
123
>>> pair_42_81(add)
123
```

We can call the function directly, and `123` is returned, or we can have `pair_42_81()` do it for us, and the same result is returned to us. Simple!

All this works because functions are objects and can be passed around like other variables, and because `pair_42_81` has `a = 42` and `c = 81` stored in a closure, and will use those to call a given object `f` with those two arguments.

Next up are `cdr()` and `car()`, which will return either the first or last element of a pair. If `cons(a, b)` produces `pair(f)` returning `f(a, b)`, then `cdr()` and `car()` must each create a function to pass to `pair()` that'll extract either `a` or `b`.

So create a nested function in each, and have `cdr()` and `car()` call `pair()` with that function. The nested function does the work of picking either `a` or `b`, and returns that value. Then return the result of the call to the outside world:

```
def car(pair):
    def return_first(a, b):
        return a
    return pair(return_first)

def cdr(pair):
    def return_last(a, b):
        return b
    return pair(return_last)
```

`pair(return_first)` calls `return_first(a, b)`, `a` is returned, and `car()` can return that to the caller:

```
>>> car(cons(42, 81))
42
```

and the same applies to `pair(return_last)`, only now `b` is returned:

```
>>> cdr(cons(42, 81))
81
```

You may be interested in the background of these operations; `car`, `cdr` and `cons` come from LISP, where `cons a b` *Constructs* a cell with two pointers (explaining the name), and `car` (meaning *Contents of the Address part of the Register number* in the IBM 704 instruction set LISP was created on) and `cdr` (meaning *Contents of the Decrement part of the Register number* in 704 language) take the first and remainder parts of such a cell. See [this Wikipedia article on the names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I think it's easier to get `cons(3,4)(lambda a, b: a)` but it's pretty hard for me to actually write the proper nested function which allow inner function get to access the original parameter like (3,4) within car and cdr

Comment: Great explanation! Much easier to understand than just having a solution.

Answer (score 2):

`cons` is a function which takes two arguments, `a` and `b` and returns a function `pair`.

The function `pair` takes a function `f` as an argument which consumes two arguments.

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair

f = lambda n, m: n**2 + m**3
car = lambda n, m: n
cdr = lambda n, m: m
print(cons(2, 3)(f))
print(cons(2, 3)(car))
print(cons(2, 3)(cdr))
```

`f` returns `31 = 2**2 + 3**3`

Note how `cons` has two times the parenthesis `(...)` - once, for its own call and another time for the returned functions call.

Please note [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52481994/562769) to be able to call `car(cons(2, 3))`. You might also be interested in [Why would a program use a closure?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/285941/25699)

Comment: In the context of the assignment, though, you would never actually call `cons(2,3)` on a function like `f`; its purpose is to take either `car` or `cdr` as an argument to retrieve the appropriate value from the tuple.

Comment: (You do still want to be able to call `car(cons(2,3))`, though; `car` and `cdr` need an additional level of indirection to allow that.)

Comment: @chepner I've added a comment to Martijn Pieters answer

Answer (score 2):

This is called a *closure*. Two basic elements

- the `pair` function knows the values of `a` and `b`. They are just like local variables in that respect
- the `cons` function returns *a function*, not a value. You have to call the result again

So, when you call `cons(a, b)` you get a function that does something to `a` and `b`, only it doesn't know what yet. You have to pass another function for that. Eg

```
 my_f = cons(1, 2)
 result = my_f(lambda x, y: x + y)
 print(result) # 3
```

How this is related to your assignment is not very clear. I would *only assume* that for `car`, you only want the element `a` (the head), and for `cdr` you want the element `b`  (the rest of the list). So, the functions would just return the one argument and ignore the other. Eg

```
car_f = lambda x, y: x
cdr_f = lambda x, y: y
```

Comment: It's an implementation tuples in lambda calculus; `cons` returns a functional encoding of a tuple, where you retrieve the first or second element of the tuple by calling the tuple on the appropriate accessor. It's a reversal of the usual data-centric implementation. You don't call `car(some_tuple)`; you call `some_tuple(car)` instead.

Comment: @chepner: aa, ok then, makes more sense that way.

Answer (score 1):

I manually converted `cons` function the Javascript version and then implemented the quiz:

> cons(a, b) constructs a pair, and car(pair) and cdr(pair) returns the first and last element of that pair. For example, car(cons(3, 4)) returns 3, and cdr(cons(3, 4)) returns 4.Given this implementation of cons:

```
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)
    return pair
```

> Implement car and cdr.

Here is the solution

```js
function cons(a, b) {
  function pair(f) {
    return f(a, b);
  }
  return pair;
}

function car(pair) {
 return pair((a, b) => a);
};

function cdr(pair) {
 return pair((a, b) => b);
};

console.log(car(cons(3,4)));
console.log(cdr(cons(3,4)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda expressions

```py
def cons(a, b):
    def pair(f):
        return f(a, b)

    return pair

def car(pair):
    return pair(lambda a, b: a)

def cdr(pair):
    return pair(lambda a, b: b)
```